# Do weapons and spells in the off-hand suffer from reduced effectiveness?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When dual wielding, is there any penalty to the offhand weapon, whether of damage or attack speed? What about a spell equipped on that slot? Or is the dragonborn ambidextrous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dragonborn is ambidexterous, but refuses to wield a shield in their right hand. Magic and weapons can be used in any combination of Right / Left, Left / Right, etc.

The Dual-Wield "penalty" as it were, is that you cannot block when dual-wielding. (Even though you could normally block with a single weapon if your offhand is free.)

Comment: He / She also wont poison weapons that are in the left hand.

Comment: @DeanMc that can be worked around, though, since you can poison a weapon, sheath it, equip another weapon, and poison *that*. It's not optimal, but it is an option.