# Is my character ambidextrous?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do weapons and spells in the off-hand suffer from reduced effectiveness?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35274/do-weapons-and-spells-in-the-off-hand-suffer-from-reduced-effectiveness)

In Skyrim for the PC, I find the fact that my left hand is bound to the right mouse button, and my right hand is bound to the left mouse button (by default) a little strange as a first time Elder Scrolls player.

I've remapped the keys, but now I wonder, will swinging my Mace in my left hand all the sudden make me suffer any kind of damage penalty?  Is my character ambidextrous such that I do the same damage with weapons and spells regardless of which hand I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Dovakhiin is, in fact, ambidextrous.